# Method not found: 'System.Type System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetTypeFromCLSID(System.Guid)'

Tags: c#, interop, visual-studio-2013

I spent a good deal of time writing this program on my dev box, after moving it to our production boxes I get the error below. Just an FYI I don't have any control over what is installed and what can be installed, how can I make this work? Under both framework on both computers we have v1.0.3705, v1.1.4322, v2.0.50727, v3.0, v3.5, 4.0.30319. Also the program I used to create the app is Visual Studio 2013 Pro.

Thanks

> See the end of this message for details on invoking  just-in-time
>   (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ******* *Exception Text* ********* System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Type
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetTypeFromCLSID(System.Guid)'.
>   at C_Sharp_version.Form1.button4_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>
> ******* *Loaded Assemblies* ********* mscorlib
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.239 (RTMGDR.030319-2300)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- C Sharp version
>       Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
>       CodeBase: file:///gordonc$/Desktop/C%20Sharp%20version%20(2).exe
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.235 built by: RTMGDR
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Drawing
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.236 built by: RTMGDR
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;


namespace C_Sharp_version
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void FindAndReplace(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application doc, object findText, object replaceWithText)
        {
            //options
            object matchCase = false;
            object matchWholeWord = true;
            object matchWildCards = false;
            object matchSoundsLike = false;
            object matchAllWordForms = false;
            object forward = true;
            object format = false;
            object matchKashida = false;
            object matchDiacritics = false;
            object matchAlefHamza = false;
            object matchControl = false;
            object read_only = false;
            object visible = true;
            object replace = 2;
            object wrap = 1;
            //execute find and replace
            doc.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
                ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openInfDoc = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (openInfDoc.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string strInfDocLocation = openInfDoc.FileName;

                MessageBox.Show(strInfDocLocation);
                InfDocLocationtxt.Text = strInfDocLocation; 
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openNetdoc = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openNetdoc.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string strNetDocLocation = openNetdoc.FileName;

                MessageBox.Show(strNetDocLocation);
                NetDocLocationtxt.Text = strNetDocLocation;
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openChkdoc = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openChkdoc.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string strChkDocLocation = openChkdoc.FileName;

                MessageBox.Show(strChkDocLocation);
                ChkDocLocationtxt.Text = strChkDocLocation;
            }
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            object fileName = Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, InfDocLocationtxt.Text);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application { Visible = true };
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ReadOnly: false, Visible: true);
            aDoc.Activate();
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<ServerName>", textBox1.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Domain>", textBox2.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Ip>", textBox3.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Engineer>", textBox4.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Date>", textBox5.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Project>", textBox6.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Cluster>", textBox7.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<DocNumber>", textBox8.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Author>", textBox9.Text);


        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            object fileName = Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, NetDocLocationtxt.Text);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application { Visible = true };
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ReadOnly: false, Visible: true);
            aDoc.Activate();
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<ServerName>", textBox1.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Domain>", textBox2.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Ip>", textBox3.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Engineer>", textBox4.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Date>", textBox5.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Project>", textBox6.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Cluster>", textBox7.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<DocNumber>", textBox8.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Author>", textBox9.Text);
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            object fileName = Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, ChkDocLocationtxt.Text);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application { Visible = true };
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ReadOnly: false, Visible: true);
            aDoc.Activate();
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<ServerName>", textBox1.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Domain>", textBox2.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Ip>", textBox3.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Engineer>", textBox4.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Date>", textBox5.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Project>", textBox6.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Cluster>", textBox7.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<DocNumber>", textBox8.Text);
            FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Author>", textBox9.Text);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

it seems to me as a `.NET Framework` `compatibility` issue.

**Problem :** you have developed your application in your local machine with heigher version of `.NET Framework` and running the same on remote pc having Lower Version of`.NET Framework`.

Note : if you target your application to run on `Heigher` Version of `.NET Framework` it wont run on lower versions.

**Solution :** you need to target it to `.NET Framework` Lower Version available on your remote PC to run on remote pc.

**Step 1:**  right click on `project` - select `properties`

**Step 2:**  change the `Target Framework` from `.NET Framework  x.x` to `.NET Framework x.y`.

Note : where `x.x` is heigher and `x.y` is lower version available on remote pc or any lower version.

Comment: Well... ok, but how can you prevent this exception to happen because as far as I can see, it cannot be catched by a try/catch statement. Users don't have to be up to date and don't have to see the app crashing because of this...

Comment: Oliver -  If you check for the installed framework version before any other code is executed you can "catch" / prevent the exception before it occurs. Micorosoft's website has example code on how to determine the installed version by looking at the registry.  

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Note the GetVersion code must be separate from the rest of your code. If you insert the GetVersion method into your main and the code causing the crash is there your program will still crash. A band aid fix is create a Main and RealMain. Stick GetVersion in Main. If version is compatible , call RealMain otherwise display helpful upgrade framework message...

Comment: Pretty late, but... Just to make sure I understand -  if you target the application to lower .NET Framework, then `Type.GetTypeFromCLSID()` will be used instead of `Marshal.GetTypeFromCLSID()`?

Comment: I installed a latest version of .NET framework on remote computer and this error disappeared. Thanks.