# Method not found: 'System.Type System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetTypeFromCLSID9System.Guid)'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, windows

```
Method not found: 'System.Type System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetTypeFromCLSID9System.Guid)'. 

See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box. 

************** Exception Text ************** 
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Type System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetTypeFromCLSID(System.Guid)'.
at WindowsApplication7.ModsToInstall.MyExtract() 
at WindowsApplication7.ModsToInstall.Install() 
at WindowsApplication7.ModsToInstall.YtButton2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m) 
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam) 


************** Loaded Assemblies ************** 
mscorlib 
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0 
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1022 (RTMGDR.030319-1000) 
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll 
---------------------------------------- 
WindowsApplication7 
Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0 
Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0 
CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/llupulescu/Desktop/Svatekl2's%20Extended%20ModPack%209.1%20v1.1.exe 
---------------------------------------- 
Microsoft.VisualBasic 
Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0 
Win32 Version: 10.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel 
CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll 
----------------------------------------<
```

- So I'm thinking the problem is the .Net FrameWork
- But I'm not sure... Could it be?
- P.S I'm new here (2nd post so far), if something looks weird or not
  "HQ" sorry :/

Comment: Is this ASP.NET, Windows Forms, or WPF?

Comment: @JohnSaunders seems `Windows Application`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search yielded this:

[Method not found: 'System.Type System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetTypeFromCLSID(System.Guid)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440822/method-not-found-system-type-system-runtime-interopservices-marshal-gettypefro)

It might be a compatibility issue?  Check out that article and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes... I took a look at his question! It looks like it could be a compatibility issue. Sadly at this moment I don't have anyone I could check with who has a older version of .Net FrameWork to test if that's what is causing the problem. But by looking over the code, does it look like it's a compatibility issue? I'm hoping it is!